# PHP curl return 403 but not the shell command

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I'm trying to implement a functionnality like facebook, when you paste a link it's grabbing some information (h1, desc, images, ...) from the page and display them.

I already face several issues that I managed to fix (gzip, cookies, user agent, ...) but on this one I'm not sure what is blocking my request.

The link in question is http://www.mixcloud.com

Here is my PHP script:

```
protected function getContent()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
        'Accept: */*',
       // 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
       // 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2',
       // 'Cache-Control: no-cache',
       // 'Connection: keep-alive'
    );

    $debug = TRUE;

    // Set the request type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, $debug);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->referrer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $debug);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($data);die;

    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Here is the verbose response:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f937504e400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f937504e400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.mixcloud.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 46.23.65.210...
* Connected to www.mixcloud.com (46.23.65.210) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5
Host: www.mixcloud.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: https://www.google.com.au
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
* Server nginx/1.5.8 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.5.8
< Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 06:39:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.mixcloud.com left intact
string(376) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nServer: nginx/1.5.8\r\nDate: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 06:39:45 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.5.8</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Now if I try to execute the curl command in the shell it's working fine:

```
$ curl -i 'http://www.mixcloud.com' -v
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fe28b004000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fe28b004000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.mixcloud.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 46.23.65.210...
* Connected to www.mixcloud.com (46.23.65.210) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: www.mixcloud.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 06:41:30 GMT
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 06:41:30 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 194847
Content-Length: 194847
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
* Server gunicorn/0.17.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: gunicorn/0.17.4
Server: gunicorn/0.17.4
< Vary: Cookie, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, X-Ignore-Block
Vary: Cookie, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, X-Ignore-Block
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-content-type-options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: csrftoken=ciOosbUNp5EL8t5tiQQzkoeaJIDJ3VfO; Domain=.mixcloud.com; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 06:41:30 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=ciOosbUNp5EL8t5tiQQzkoeaJIDJ3VfO; Domain=.mixcloud.com; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 06:41:30 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: eventstream=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: eventstream=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/

< 
<!DOCTYPE html> ...
```

I know that the cURL for PHP and cURL are different, but I can't see what I am missing.
Anyone?

Cheers, 
Maxime

Comment: One obvious difference is the Referer request header, but I'm not sure whether any server would bother about that.

Comment: Yeah but no... I just try to add some headers information thinking that nginx was detecting a bot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've found what was the issue. It was the user-agent.
It's really weird. I was using this user-agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5
```

With this user agent I was getting a 403. I've updated it using the following one:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
```

And it's now working well. I can't believe that people are still rejecting request for specific user agent...